# Does Bigquery Storage Write API Create a new connection for each append_row in default stream?

Tags: google-bigquery, google-bigquery-storage-api

When I check the `Concurrent connections` [quota](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quotas#write-api-limits) for Bigquery Storage Write API, it says 1,000 in a region; 10,000 in a multi-region. This number seems very small. Is this limit per project or per stream? And if I append_rows to the same default stream from different instances at the same time will those count towards the connection limit?

Answer (score 0):

The Concurrent connection quota is applied per project where the stream is initiated.

> The concurrent connections quota is based on the client project that initiates the Storage Write API request

> The initiating project is the project associated with the API key or the service account

Basically, the default stream reuses a single [connection](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/write-api#connections) for all the append_row requests within a stream, however as I understand your use case, these instances will fall under the Application-created streams which can only have a single connection hence initializing an append_row requests from multiple instances to the same default stream in effect creates multiple connections that shares the same connection limit.

You can review the [BigQuery Storage Write API best practices](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/write-api-best-practices) to understand more about the relationship between a stream and a connection.